# Типы в функциях выделения памяти на Си и С++

Tags: c++, c, память, malloc, преобразование-типов

Столкнулся с такой проблемой на `С++`: при выделении памяти нужно явное преобразование типа `void *` к типу указателя, которому выделяется память, а для этого нужно указать тип указателя. Тобишь нужен такой код:

```
p = (int *) malloc (10 * sizeof (int));
```

Однако, программируя на `Си`, я привык делать код независимым от типов, т.е. выделение памяти проиходило как:

```
p = malloc (10 * sizeof *p);
```

При таком подходе можно не боясь менять тип указателя (например с `long` на `long long` - что приходилось делать часто) и при этом точно ничего плохого не произойдет. В С++ впринципе тоже можно записать также, но перед `malloc` обязательно нужно преобразование указателя. Можно ли сделать его не зависимым от типа указателя (всмысле не указывать его явно)? Как это сделать?

Comment: можно сделать `typedef long новоеимятипа;`, везде вместо `long` писать имя нового типа, и тогда если захочется поменять `long` на `long long`, достаточно будет поменять только в одном месте

Comment: это весьмы узкий подход - в другом случае может потребоваться заменить `int` на `char` или еще что - не каждый же раз создавать новый тип

Comment: Точно-точно! А то вот бывает, изменяешь размер массива, и его нужно в трех циклах менять - не создавать же из-за этого новую константу!

Comment: не понял при чем тут размер массива?

Comment: А это как магическая константа. Не хотите что-то менять в куче мест - используйте новый идентификатор...

Comment: ну да, так вопрос именно по этому поводу: я не хочу менять в куче мест явно указанный тип (тот же `long`), при этом у меня есть тип указателя - желательно поменять только сам тип указателя. При этом, если я сделаю так, как предлагал diraria, то изменятся все типы `long` что есть в коде - а это может быть совершенно не к чему, а то и вообще навредит. Мне то надо изменить только тип указателя - одного конкретного!

Comment: например: мне нужно поменять указатель с `int` на `char`, но помимо этого `int` у меня есть другие инты! Они же тоже изменятся на char - а мне это зачем? скорее всего это вообще навредит.

Comment: Без проблем. `int *p = (__typeof(p)__)malloc(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваше желание избежать повторения одного и того же имени типа несколько раз - понятно и естественно. Однако в С++ это достигается другими методами. В частности, именно для этого были введены такие свойства языка, как `decltype` и `auto`. Например вы можете написать так

```
auto *p = new int[10];
```

или

```
int *p = new std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*p)>[10];
```

В обоих случаях вы избежали повторного упоминания имени типа. Второй вариант по своей сути ближе к вашему варианту с `malloc` и может быть записан как

```
int *p = static_cast<decltype(p)>(malloc(10 * sizeof *p));
```

Это, конечно, более громоздко, но С и С++ - это разные языки.

Comment: вот это ближе к тому, что требовалось. Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

В С++ не стоит использовать `malloc`, предпочтительнее - если уж совсем нельзя обойтись без явного выделения памяти с помощью интеллектуальных указателей или контейнеров - использовать `new`.

Ну, как вариант - вот (упрощенно):

```
template<typename T>
void alloc(T*&p, size_t N)
{
    p = (T*)malloc(N);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    long * l;
    alloc(l,200);
}
```

Comment: но `new` тоже требует явного указания типа: `p = new int [10];`. Как сдесь обойтися без явного указания типа указателя?

Comment: В общем случае - никак. Вопросы безопасности... :)

Comment: Ну или см. дополненный ответ. Просто функция не знает тип указателя, которому вы хотите выполнять присваивание...

Comment: блин, но это чертовски неудобно! Вот пример: проходил онлайн курсы по алгоритмам - нужно было отправлять на проверку исходный код, написанный по задачам. При этом при проверке использовалась 32-х битная система, в которой тип `long` был равен типу `int`. На моем же компе тип `long` больше `int`. Из-за этого приходилось менять указатели с `long` на `long long`, когда я забывал сделать это сразу. На С++ это потенциально приведет к ошибкам... Это конечно плохо

Comment: Это безопасно :) А если нужно типы менять - то к вашим услугам `using`/`typedef`. Вас же не удивляет и не раздражает неудобство при использовании "магических констант"? А чем принципиально отличаются типы?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, auto p = new int [10];

Comment: @АндрейМоскаленко и? Это к чему?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch к сожалению неправильно понял сообщение выше "new тоже требует явного указания типа", подумал что вы говорите о типе указателя, а с auto не придется менять тип указателя - т.е меняем тип всего 1 раз, меньше никак не выйдет)